Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:Class org.testng.CommandLineArgs does not have member field 'java.lang.Integer port'
I'm trying to execute a file in TestNG without any xml file, just a direct run as shown on youtube. However, I'm getting the error below. Why is this?
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Class org.testng.CommandLineArgs does not have member field 'java.lang.Integer port'
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:69)

TestNG version  - 7.10.2
Eclipse version - Version: Oxygen.3 Release (4.7.3)
Java version - java 21.0.2
What am I missing out?
I'm trying to execute a API in rest assured in TestNG.

Where on YouTube? Why are you using a JDK and TestNG version from 2024 but a release of Eclipse from 2018?

Add a [mre]. The information must be in the question, not in YouTube.

Your Eclipse is way too old. Eclipse Oxygen.3 is more than six years and 25 releases behind. It was released many years before Java 21 and it provides support up to Java 10 only which was the latest Java version at this point of time.

Just change the testNG version from 7.10.x to an older version like 7.7.x or 7.8.x.
It will 100% work.

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors
